# VSCode Error on <script> tag in .svelte file

Tags: visual-studio-code, svelte

I'm having a really odd visual issue in VSCode when working on a Svelte project.
All of my files that end in .svelte and have a  tag VSCode is showing a little squiggly line with the error: "Error in svelte.config.js SyntaxError: unexpected reserved word svelte".

Does anybody know how to get rid of this error?
It's not affecting the svelte compile or runtime at all, it's just visually annoying and makes all my svelte files look like they have errors.

Here is a screenshot of the error in a brand new file with an empty  tag:

[image: Error Screenshot]

And here is my entire svelte.config.js file:

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-auto';
const config = {
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter(),
        methodOverride: {
            allowed: ['PATCH', 'DELETE']
        }
    }
};
export default config;
```

Comment: That's strange. Does it make a difference if you try either of these:
- Make the PATCH/DELETE lowercase
- Add `/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */` above config

Also, have you got any svelte based extensions?

Comment: This is the weirdest thing! I first changed PATCH/DELETE to lowercase - no change. Then added that type/import line - no change. Then changed PATCH/DELETE back to uppercase - no change. Removed the type/import line - no more error. So, essentially, I'm back to where I started, but without the VSCode error. I thought that /* */ was for comments in JS, why would that @type line have any effect?

Comment: Forgot to add that all I have as far as extensions go are:
Community Material Theme, 
Python, and 
Svelte for VS Code

Comment: Hmmm that's strange. Maybe just reloading the window would've fixed it perhaps? As in `ctrl shift p` then reload. Weird.

So `/** */` is JSDoc, which allows you to write documentation for code right. However, you can do @type to specify a type for that thing inline like that and it just basically imports that sveltekit type and says use it for this.

Same thing as `import type { x } from y` and then using it in Typescript like `const config: x = ...` in your case. I guess the JSDoc is more friendlier if you aren't using typescript :)